# How to decrease the quantity of questions about increasing/decreasing quantity with MongoDB and ReactJS

Tags: discussion

We seem to be getting absolutely inundated with low-quality questions about this topic.  Most lack *both* a clear description of the problem and relevant code.

Here are some examples:

- [how do I update quantity in mongo and UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72175130/208273)
- [How can i increase the value of quantity of Item in MongoDB with Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72173484/208273)
- [How I can Quantity decrease in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72167236/208273)
- [How to make a react mongodb quantity incriease and discrease?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72161824/208273)
- [How to reduce product quantity by 1 from mongodb using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72161795/208273)
- [show quantity Sold Out if quantity is zero By MongoDB Database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72161543/208273)
- [How can decrease quantity to react from MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72161386/208273)
- [How to update quantity in mongodb data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72160134/208273)
- [MongoDB cannot update value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72159683/208273)
- [How can I increase quantity by clicking that delivered button in react.js and also add it at MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72158120/208273)
- [how to increase and decrease in mongodb with onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72157479/208273)
- [How can i update the UI while update collection property from server api?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72156463/208273) (clear problem statement, but no MRE)
- [Update one property in MongoDB and update UI without refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72151977/208273) (this is the clearest one yet!)
- [How to update product quantity in MongoDB with node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72149718/208273)
- [How can i update qty quantity in mongodb database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72149052/208273)
- [How can I use Mongo DB's database to subtract and add a quantity from an item using the put method from a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72139529/208273) (one of the clearest ones; still has formatting issues and no clear problem statement, though)

Similar but not specifically about changing product quantity:

- [How Can I post cart order List to Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72159062/208273)

Also maybe related, but express.js instead:

- [having Null in update, using express.js. get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72173331/208273)

...etc.  I got bored of looking.  This is just the last 3-4 days of them.

It seems like there's some sort of class or project that these people are doing, and I'm guessing they've been told to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

My questions, for your consideration:

1. Does anyone know the source of these?
2. Do we have any suitable duplicates explaining, generally, how to do this task?
3. Any ideas on how to handle this and/or make it stop?

Comment: all users that have indicated their location come from Bangladesh. Maybe origin is some of their local university or course. But without explicitly asking some of them I don't think we can deduct the real source.

Comment: Most likely some nation-wide exams are coming up? We always get crap peaks when that happens.

Comment: The exam period has started in a number of countries by now. Feels weird though, I always assumed most of these questions came from assignments and not exams, largely due to time constraints. People who cheat on exams tend to do it with people they work with, assuming it's a home exam anyway.

Comment: Maybe the institutions are in on it as well, with the wrong incentives (e.g., not a reputation to protect)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Interesting hypothesis. I’ve definitely seen users admit that their university instructors had put them up to posting a question on Stack Overflow. Seems possible.

Comment: WRT a general duplicate. From what I can gather they have a front-end react app which needs to send an API request (POST) with some information about a particular item. The backend needs to accept the request, find that item in a Mongo database and add the amount from the request to it. The core issue with a duplicate closure (currently) is that it seems that every individual is struggling with a different part of the problem. There are several distinct components at play which likely each individually have dupe targets, but as a single question would be rather broad.

Comment: They surely have no research in common.

Comment: I don’t know about the mongodb area but the unity3d area suffers the same. We get an influx of the same code with variations on the same questions. Part of me is pleased thet education is saying use sources for ideas and solutions. But it seems it comes over as if you aren’t understanding SO will do it for you.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine When studying for an exam you often have access to tests from previous years and then ask about those as part of your studies. And if schools hand out old exams perhaps even nation-wide... there will be a whole lot of students with identical questions.

Comment: @Lundin Most old exams tend to come with solutions, at least here. I highly doubt that's it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250814/how-to-reduce-quantity-from-mongodb-using-node-js I guess I just spot another one. I am not sure if the "trend" has stopped.

Answer (score 21):

While the overall goal is the same "modifying some quantity", the methods and problems are all different, that is if you can actually get them to show what code they were having problems with. Most of those questions should simply be closed as unclear, rather than being used as canonical of anything. If someone manages to ask an actual good question about how to do X using Y and Z, then we may mean business. But for now, just close and delete these.